# Keras fit_generator is too slow while image proccesing

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network

I'm making a CNN to guess a picture whether it's a dog or cat. I'm using Keras for this purpose. I have training set size of 8000 images and when I run the code, time for each epoch to be completed is around 30 minutes. Total number of epochs is 25. How can I run the code faster? By the way my RAM is 8GB.

```
# Part 1 - Building the CNN

# Importing the Keras libraries and packages
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D
from keras.layers import MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers import Flatten
from keras.layers import Dense

# Initialising the CNN
classifier = Sequential()

# Step 1 - Convolution
classifier.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape=(64, 64, 3), activation='relu'))

# Step 2 - Pooling
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

# Step 3 - Flattening
classifier.add(Flatten())

# Step 4 - Full connection
classifier.add(Dense(units=128, activation='relu'))
classifier.add(Dense(units=1, activation='sigmoid')) 

# Compiling the CNN
classifier.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

# Part 2 - Fitting the CNN to the images
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
        rescale=1./255,
        shear_range=0.2,
        zoom_range=0.2,
        horizontal_flip=True)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        'dataset/training_set',
        target_size=(64, 64),
        batch_size=32,
        class_mode='binary')

test_set = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        'dataset/test_set',
        target_size=(64, 64),
        batch_size=32,
        class_mode='binary')

classifier.fit_generator(
        training_set,
        steps_per_epoch=8000,
        epochs=25,
        validation_data=test_set,
        validation_steps=2000)
```

Comment: enable GPU mode

Comment: if you system not having tensorflow-gpu first install it .if you do not want to install then your kaggle platform GPU or google colab  GPU for execution